# AWS Client VPN vs EC2 machine with VPN Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn

I have to move Windows Server to AWS , and this server to be accessible only by VPN.
There are two options:

- AWS Client VPN (managed service where AWS provide endpoint when users
  to connect, and pricing per connected users.)
- AWS EC2 instance where I can install OpenVPN and to allow access to Windows Server only by VPN IP.

The question is are these 2 options equal, on point of Speed? If I choose the option with EC2 the speed will not be worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 instance speed depends on its type and size. E.g. `t3.micro` will be slower than `m5.2xlarge`. Check out the [**EC2 Instance Types**](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) for details about CPU, memory, and network throughput.

The question whether *AWS Client VPN* is faster than *EC2 based VPN* can’t be answered unless we discuss specific instance types. Big enough instance will be as fast or faster than Client VPN.

Another question is what are you going to use the VPN for? If it’s only *Remote Desktop* you won’t need much speed, it can reasonably run over quite a slow speed, using a small instance. On the other hand if you’re going to *transfer large files* all the time you may need a higher throughput and bigger instance.

**My recommendation:** start with a smaller, cheaper instance, e.g. `t3.small` and see if the speed is sufficient. If not *change the instance size* to a bigger one. That can be done while retaining all the data. Simply *stop - change size - start*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you. By speed I mean the network throughput. Looks like I found the answer of my question. EC2 instances have some limits of network performance https://dzone.com/articles/ec2-network-performance-of-t3. Which mean with t3.micro 
 I can pass around 60Mbit.

Comment: @DobriLDobriLov The point is it’s easy to switch between instance types if you find that what you start with is too slow or on the other hand underutilised.

Comment: @DobriLDobriLov Anyway if this answer helped please upvote and accept it. Thanks!